# Perforce stream - can you exclude a directory but include specific files in that directory?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have a Perforce stream where I am excluding certain binary folders, as in
exclude Binaries/Win64/...

But there are a couple of files in that directory that I do want in the stream. Is there a way to list exceptions to the exclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always override a more general rule with a more specific one:

```
share ...
exclude Binaries/Win64/...
share Binaries/Win64/foo
share Binaries/Win64/bar
```